# memory read failed for 0x4e00000000 at the end of the code when array's numbers are randomly generated

Tags: c, sorting, memory

So I'm trying to apply (in C) randomly generated numbers to an array which will be sorted with Quick sort. There is no problem with generating numbers and sorting, but at the end of the code I have an error telling me there was a problem with memory reading.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


void generate(int AR[], int n){



    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int num = (rand()%100);
        AR[i]=num;

    }
    }// end of generate

void swap(int *a, int *b){
    int temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
} //end of  swap


int sort(int AR[], int beg, int end){
    int pivot= AR[end];
    int a=(beg-1);

    for(int i=beg; i<=end-1; i++){

        if(AR[i]<pivot){
            a++;
            swap(&AR[i], &AR[a]);
        }//end of if
        } //end of i<end-1
    swap(&AR[a+1], &AR[end]);
    return (a+1);

} //end of sort


void Quick_sort(int AR[], int beg, int end){

    if(beg<end){

        int placed_PV=sort(AR, beg, end);

        Quick_sort(AR, beg, placed_PV-1);
        Quick_sort(AR, placed_PV+1, end);

    } //end of  if beg<end
    }//end of  Quick sort




int main(){


    int AR[]={};
    int n=10;


    generate(AR, n);

    printf("\n");
    printf("Nieposortowana tablica:");
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
                printf("%d,", AR[i]);
    printf("\n");

    Quick_sort(AR, 0, n-1);

    printf("Posortowana tablica:");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d,", AR[i]);
    printf("\n");
                                        } //end of code
```

error message is
`error: memory read failed for 0x4e00000000`

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x4e00000000)`

Where is the mistake I've made?

Comment: `int AR[]={};` is an array with 0 elements. You cannot access any element of it without invoking *undefined behavior*

Comment: Instead of `int AR[]={}; int n=10;` why not `int AR[10]` and `sizeof(AR / AR[0])`?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `int n=10; int AR[n];` but you cannot initialise a VLA like that, and you don't have to since function `generate()` does that.

Comment: Ok, I see it now guys. Everything works fine now. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have this:

```
    int AR[]={};
    int n=10;
```

which is wrong because this array `AR` has only one element(due to this initialization) ,so you can't access ten elements of it.

fix like this

```
int AR[10]={0};
```